# How to find a LinkedIn users web link using REGEX C#

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to match LinkedIn URLs from a string. The issue is, my Regex isn't working and won't match with any LinkedIn URLs, any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Example URLs I'm trying to match:

> https://www.linkedin.com/company/tremolo/about/
>
> https://www.linkedin.com/in/adamblakney/

My Regex:

```
  Regex linkedRegex = new Regex(@"(http(s)?:\/\/([\w]+\.)?linkedin\.com\/in\/[A-z0-9_-]+\/?",
  RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

All code for clarity:

```
  string ps = driver.PageSource;
  string words = string.Join(" ", ps);
  Regex linkedRegex = new Regex(@"(http(s)?:\/\/([\w]+\.)?linkedin\.com\/in\/[A-z0-9_-]+\/?",
  RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

  //find items that matches with our pattern
  MatchCollection linkedMatches = linkedRegex.Matches(words);
  linkedin = linkedMatches[0].ToString();
```

Comment: What is the issue? Note there is one `)` missing in the pattern. You must be getting `Not enough )'s` exception

Comment: And more, there is no `/in/` in `https://www.linkedin.com/company/tremolo/about/`, so you should probably just use `\S*` instead of `in\/[A-z0-9_-]+\/?`